# create polylines in gmap and generate image

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to generate a gmap image in asp.net. I need to specify different latitude and longitude and generate google map image with polylines. So far, i am able to create image with the below code :

```
protected void btnMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Save_Image("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false");
}

private void Save_Image(string URL)
{
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  string strFileName = DateTime.Now.GetHashCode().ToString() + ".png";
  client.DownloadFile(URL, Server.MapPath("~/images/" + strFileName));
  imgGmap.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + strFileName;
}
```

I am not able to find the way to pass the longitude and latitude in this url. I have checked [this](http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html) blog which is doing the same thing, but i am not finding the way to generate image with this demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Paths) you should be able to specify the path for a polyline like so:

path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397

e.g.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|40.702147,-74.015794|40.711614,-74.012318|40.718217,-73.998284
```

Alternatively you can use the [encoded polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#EncodedPolylines) format (useful for shortening the URL significantly).

And you would specify that like:

&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:**polyline_data**

To get that polyline_data, you could use the online form here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Alternatively write your algorithm based on the specification here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Comment: if i add 1000 langs and lats , then will it be a problem in calling `webclient` url lenght ?

Comment: yes, you're likely to exceed the max length of a URL, anything over 2000 chars is probably too long

Comment: However you may be able to use the [Encoded Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) instead

Comment: can you please share some idea how to use it in c#

Comment: I've updated my answer... I'm not writing your C# algorithm to convert coordinates into encoded data, but it shouldn't be too hard (someone else may have done this already out there)

Comment: how to pass polyline_data to enc parameter

Comment: I have downloaded encoder from http://code.google.com/p/csharp-polyline-encoder/ and passing data as in json format in enc parameter , but its not returning image with point

Comment: Give me an example URL you're using with the enc data please

Comment: after serializing the points its coming like `{"encodedPoints":"kslwFvewbMez@wTgh@uvA","encodedLevels":"PPP"}` how should i pass this in the parameter

Comment: I assume just `Save_Image("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false&enc=" + encodedPoints);`  I don't know if you also need to specify the encodedLevels